# Discrepancies between Memtest86+ 2.11 and 5.01 test results

Tags: memory, ddr2, memtest86+

I am testing a few DDR-2 memory modules with Memtest86+. For one of the modules, Memtest86+ version 2.11 reports no problems while Memtest86+ version 5.01 reports four errors.

I have tested the same memory module on two different mainboards with both Memtest86+ versions, and version 5.01 consistently reports four errors at the same addresses while version 2.11 reports no errors.

Since until recently I have always used version 2.11 (it comes with a 2-year old antiX CD I was using), I am now not sure what I should do. What can be the cause of this discrepancy? Should I retest all my RAM with the most recent Memtest86+ version? What should I conclude: the module is bad?

**EDIT**

When testing with version 5.01 I did not use the fail safe mode. I will do it later to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the memtest86 version change-log (http://www.memtest.org/#change), every version between 2.11 and 5.01 has “fixed bugs”.  Also, version 5.01 now includes some “rewritten memory timing detection code”.  (You can also check the change-log to see if support for whatever CPU you are using was added *after* 2.11.)

Based on the change-log, my suggestion would be to use the results for the 5.01 version of the program, and discard the results of your 2.11 tests, re-testing all memory-modules.  I would also point out that if you are doing this testing because a system is experiencing instability, this instability itself is additional (but not as conclusive) evidence you may indeed have a problem with the installed memory-module.

However, if the new version reports that ALL of your memory modules have problems, a sanity-check would not be a bad idea. Some possible sanity-checks would include; moving the memory modules around into different slots, or even installing the memory in a different computer (as you have done already for at least one memory module), and then run memtest86 to see if you get the same results.

If the memory-module is still under warranty, I see no reason not to replace it.  If you need to spend money on a new memory-module, you will need to evaluate how valuable system stability is, in this situation.  Personally, I could live with an error or three on my home gaming system, but on one of my client's business server, I would insist the memory module be replaced.

Comment: I bought the modules and I am testing them. I can bring them back to the shop and have them replaced. I am now testing two more modules. One of the two has the same errors as the previous module (same four addresses). This makes me a bit suspicious that it could be a Memtest86+ bug. I have found this: http://www.sysnative.com/forums/redirect-to/?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.canardpc.com%2Fthreads%2F83346-v5.01-gives-errors-in-multi-thread-mode-but-not-in-default-mode I run in safe mode to see if there are false positives. Otherwise I will bring the modules back to the shop next Monday.

Comment: "One of the two has the same errors as the previous module (same four addresses). This makes me a bit suspicious that it could be a Memtest86+ bug."  That is indeed suspect, but since only one of the two has the same errors, this makes me LESS suspicious, than if ALL modules showed the same error.

Comment: I have tested all four modules on two different motherboards. Sometimes no error was reported, sometimes exactly four errors were reported. The errors were reported at least once for each module. The errors were always the same for all four 1GB modules.